# SymFromAddr using C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, pinvoke

I was trying to see how could I use SymFromAddr from C#. Here is what I have got.
The problem is, `DbgHelp.SymFromAddr(processHandle, (ulong)threadAddress, ref displacement, ref symbolInfo)` returns error 87. What am I doing wrong?
*Made a slight mod. The SizeOfStruct has now been populated. But no fruit.

```
static void GetThreadList(int processId, IntPtr processHandle)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Process Id: {0:X4}", processId));
    var threadCollection = Process.GetProcessById(processId).Threads.OfType<ProcessThread>();
    foreach (ProcessThread processThread in threadCollection)
    {
        ulong dwAddress = (ulong)ThreadStartAddress(processThread.Id, processHandle);
        Console.WriteLine("  Thread Id: {0:X4}, Start Address: {1:X16}",
                          processThread.Id, dwAddress);
    }
}

static IntPtr ThreadStartAddress(int threadId, IntPtr processHandle)
{
    var threadHandle = DbgHelp.OpenThread(DbgHelp.ThreadAccess.QueryInformation, false, threadId);
    if (threadHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
        throw new Win32Exception();

    IntPtr threadAddress = IntPtr.Zero;
    var buf = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(IntPtr.Size);
        try
        {
            var result = DbgHelp.NtQueryInformationThread(threadHandle,
                             DbgHelp.ThreadInfoClass.ThreadQuerySetWin32StartAddress,
                             buf, IntPtr.Size, IntPtr.Zero);
            if (0 != result)
                throw new Win32Exception(string.Format("NtQueryInformationThread failed; NTSTATUS = {0:X8}", result));
            threadAddress = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(buf);

            unsafe
            {
                ulong displacement = 0;
                uint symsetOptStatus = DbgHelp.SymSetOptions(DbgHelp.SymOpt.UNDNAME | DbgHelp.SymOpt.DEFERRED_LOADS); // Returns 6.
                if (!DbgHelp.SymInitialize(threadHandle, null, true))
                {
                    // SymInitialize failed with error C000000B.
                    Console.WriteLine("SymInitialize returned error : {0:X16}.\n", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                }
                DbgHelp.SYMBOL_INFO symbolInfo = new DbgHelp.SYMBOL_INFO();
                //symbolInfo.SizeOfStruct = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(symbolInfo);
                //symbolInfo.MaxNameLen = DbgHelp.MAX_SYM_NAME;
                //const int maxNameLen = 512;
                //int bufferSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(DbgHelp.SYMBOL_INFO)) + (DbgHelp.MAX_SYM_NAME * 2);
                //var buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bufferSize);
                //DbgHelp.SYMBOL_INFO symbolInfo = (DbgHelp.SYMBOL_INFO)buffer;
                symbolInfo.SizeOfStruct = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(DbgHelp.SYMBOL_INFO));
                symbolInfo.MaxNameLen = DbgHelp.MAX_SYM_NAME -1;

                if (DbgHelp.SymFromAddr(processHandle, (ulong)threadAddress, ref displacement, ref symbolInfo))
                {
                    // SymFromAddr returned success.
                    return threadAddress;
                }
                else
                {
                    // SymFromAddr failed with error 87.
                    Console.WriteLine("SymFromAddr returned error : {0}.\n", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                    return threadAddress;
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            DbgHelp.CloseHandle(threadHandle);
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buf);
        }
}
```

Comment: We can't see `DbgHelp`. What is it?

Comment: Error 87 means "invalid arguments".  Many possibilities, there's a lot of pinvoke to get wrong here.  Including not setting pSymbol.SizeOfStruct

Comment: @david-heffernan The DbgHelp is justa wrapper. You can get the same from http://www.koders.com/csharp/fidAB470706CB5969E4C035A4ED5335B647A1B82DB8.aspx?s=search#L30

Comment: @HansPassant It could be. As per MSDN, The SizeOfStruct is sizeof(SYMBOL_INFO) But I dont find any way to do this, since SYMBOL_INFO is an unmanaged struct. More information is available here, which is exactly same question, but unanswered. http://channel9.msdn.com/Niners/ProgrammerCS/Discussions

Comment: It is not unmanaged when you use it in C#.  Just make the last member a very large string by decorating it with MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = MAX_SYM_NAME)]

Comment: It already is,             [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 1024)]
            public string Name;

Comment: @Aczire Did you finally managed to do this? I am in the same situation, can you please share your solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I see is writing an unmanaged c++ wrapper for reading symbol info.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
        const int maxNameLen = 512;
        int bufferSize = sizeof(SYMBOL_INFO) + maxNameLen*2;
        buffer = (byte*)Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bufferSize);
        symbolInfo = (SYMBOL_INFO*)buffer;
        symbolInfo->SizeOfStruct = (uint)sizeof(SYMBOL_INFO);
        symbolInfo->MaxNameLen   = maxNameLen - 1;
```

Comment: it wont compile. Even inside an unsafe block. :( No way to `symbolInfo = (SYMBOL_INFO*)buffer; ` Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type ('DbgHelp.SYMBOL_INFO')

Comment: I Know, Changed most of it, including changing sizeof to Marshal.SizeOf, -> to ., buffer to var buffer etc. But seems the idea is same, create a buffer & make it SYMBOL_INFO type. That is what in all c++ code example. But how to in C#.

Comment: Try use:static extern bool SymFromAddr(IntPtr hProcess, ulong Address, ref ulong Displacement, SYMBOL_INFO* Symbol);