# Symbol information by address

Tags: c#

I am trying to get the symbol information from an address but I am getting error 87 (0x57) ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER, I have also found the same question here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bd3e1c89-83c7-41c3-9d5d-a41069da2555/retrieving-symbol-information-by-address-in-c?forum=netfxtoolsdev but the answer does not work for me or at least it is not clear. There is some related questions in SO like: [SymFromAddr using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12127842/symfromaddr-using-c-sharp) but it seems there is no clues to solve this.

Note: DbgHelpNative class is a wrapper of the DbgHelp.dll for C#.

This is my code:

```
static IntPtr GetThreadStartAddress(int threadId)
{

   var hThread =    OpenThread(ThreadAccess.QueryInformation, false, threadId);

   if (hThread == IntPtr.Zero) {
      throw new Win32Exception();
   }

   var buf = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(IntPtr.Size);

   try {
      var result =  NtQueryInformationThread(hThread,ThreadInfoClass.ThreadQuerySetWin32StartAddress,buf, IntPtr.Size, IntPtr.Zero);

      if (result != 0) {
        throw new Win32Exception(string.Format("NtQueryInformationThread failed; NTSTATUS = {0:X8}", result));
      }

      IntPtr threadAddress = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(buf);

      if (DbgHelpNative.SymInitialize(IntPtr.Zero, null,     false)) {

         int bufferSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(DbgHelpNative.SYMBOL_INFO)) + ((2000 - 2) * 2);

         var buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bufferSize);

         DbgHelpNative.SYMBOL_INFO symbolInfo = new DbgHelpNative.SYMBOL_INFO();

         ulong displacement = 0;

         Marshal.PtrToStructure(buffer, typeof(DbgHelpNative.SYMBOL_INFO));

         symbolInfo.SizeOfStruct = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(DbgHelpNative.SYMBOL_INFO));

         symbolInfo.MaxNameLen = 2000;


         if (DbgHelpNative.SymFromAddr(hThread, (ulong)threadAddress, out displacement, ref symbolInfo)) {
            MessageBox.Show("Success");
         } else {
            var error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            MessageBox.Show(error.ToString());
         }
      }
      return threadAddress;
   }
   finally {
      CloseHandle(hThread);
      Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buf);
   }
}
```

Comment: Try with these: `    int bufferSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(DbgHelpNative.SYMBOL_INFO));
    symbolInfo.SizeOfStruct = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(DbgHelpNative.SYMBOL_INFO));
    symbolInfo.MaxNameLen = 1024;`

Comment: And move the `Marshal.PtrToStructure(` AFTER the `symbolInfo.MaxNameLen = 1024;`

Comment: Where have you copied that code from? If I see the C/C++ code I can translated it.

Comment: Well, this code is a mix of my own knowledge and research through the internet, I have tried to do it with C# because it is easier for me in comparison with the same code in C/C++, I can't test your suggestion before 8 hours. And also I have no C/C++ to show, I'm using a  C# wrapper, anyway you have the related documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681323(v=vs.85).aspx thanks!

Comment: Yuck.  Use the [DIA SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x93ctkx8.aspx) instead please.  Included with every VS install.

Comment: @HansPassant It is only available with C++, ins't it? I would like to use C# on the top.

Comment: It provides a COM interface, usable from any language.  Google "c# dia sdk" for basic hits.

Comment: Have you tried choosing to use the Native instead of the Managed debugging? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-managed-and-native-code?view=vs-2019

I have found, in my cases, switching to pure native debugging can sometimes allow values to be viewed that would fail in the managed debugger. Specifically regarding symbol information. Might help. If not good luck :)

Answer (score 2):

The correct code is:

```
static IntPtr GetThreadStartAddress(IntPtr hProc, int threadId)
{
    IntPtr hThread = IntPtr.Zero;
    GCHandle handle = default(GCHandle);

    try
    {
        hThread = OpenThread(ThreadAccess.QueryInformation, false, threadId);

        if (hThread == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            throw new Win32Exception("OpenThread failed");
        }

        var threadAddress = new IntPtr[1];

        handle = GCHandle.Alloc(threadAddress, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        var result = NtQueryInformationThread(hThread, ThreadInfoClass.ThreadQuerySetWin32StartAddress, handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), IntPtr.Size, IntPtr.Zero);

        if (result != 0)
        {
            throw new Win32Exception(string.Format("NtQueryInformationThread failed; NTSTATUS = {0:X8}", result));
        }

        DbgHelpNative.SymSetOptions(DbgHelpNative.Options.SYMOPT_UNDNAME | DbgHelpNative.Options.SYMOPT_DEFERRED_LOADS);

        if (!DbgHelpNative.SymInitialize(hProc, null, true))
        {
            throw new Win32Exception("SymInitialize failed");
        }

        DbgHelpNative.SYMBOL_INFO symbolInfo = new DbgHelpNative.SYMBOL_INFO();

        // Look at your DbgHelpNative.SYMBOL_INFO.Name definition, there should be a SizeConst.
        // Change the 1024 to the SizeConst
        // If using Unicode, change 1024 to 1024 * 2
        // In the end SizeOfStruct should be 88, both at 32 and 64 bits, both Ansi and Unicode
        symbolInfo.SizeOfStruct = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(DbgHelpNative.SYMBOL_INFO)) - 1024;
        // Change the 1024 to the SizeConst (both for Ansi and Unicode)
        symbolInfo.MaxNameLen = 1024;

        ulong displacement;

        if (!DbgHelpNative.SymFromAddr(hProc, (ulong)threadAddress[0], out displacement, ref symbolInfo))
        {
            throw new Win32Exception("SymFromAddr failed");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Success");

        return threadAddress[0];
    }
    finally
    {
        if (hThread != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            CloseHandle(hThread);
        }

        if (handle.IsAllocated)
        {
            handle.Free();
        }
    }
}
```

**you'll have to do a small correction in the `symbolInfo.SizeOfStruct` and `symbolInfo.MaxNameLen` lines!

Note that you need both a `hProc` (a handle to the process) AND a `threadId`

For current process you can use this:

```
var proc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
int id = proc.Threads[0].Id;
IntPtr addr = GetThreadStartAddress(proc.Handle, id);
```

Note that, if you are using [this](https://github.com/deplinenoise/ig-memtrace/blob/master/tool/MemTrace/DbgHelp.cs) for the `DbgHelpNative`, I consider any PInvoke that uses Ansi instead of Unicode to be defective. Another (small, non-) problem is that the `SizeConst` in that library is set to 1024, but in the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680578(v=vs.85).aspx) examples they use `MAX_SYM_NAME`, that is 2000... I haven't ever seen a 2000 character symbol, but...)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try your solution as soon as possible. One more thing: I have not DbgHelpNative.Options.SYMOPT_UNDNAME nor DbgHelpNative.Options.SYMOPT_DEFERRED_LOADS but I have seen this in other solutions on the internet, what is the purpose of this two options?

Comment: @AlejandroMorán Copy their values from [here](https://github.com/deplinenoise/ig-memtrace/blob/master/tool/MemTrace/DbgHelp.cs#L47). Probably you have them under other names... Check your `SymSetOptions` what accepts. I don't know what they are used for... They where present in a **working** example I found :-)

Comment: Hi @xanatos ! after a long time I have been trying to achieve the same objective. So far I can see the threads in the process and their start address but I am not able to find module or symbol information, so it's impossible for me to identify a certain thread within the process, any other idea I could try?

Comment: and another question that I ask myself now is "how do I get a handle to that external process?" to send it to the SymInitialize first param, that's one of the multiple issues I have.

Comment: @AlejandroMorán For the second one, it is easy: `var process = Process.GetProcesses(); var handle = process.Handle`. There are static methods inside the `Process` class to search for processes by id or by name. For the first one, I don't even know what symbols are :-) This isn't my field of programming. I can do PInvoke quite well (so I was able to check the code) but I don't do low level programming.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've tried that way but it fails (I don't know really why since the errors triggered are not very helpful)